# How to get total vCPU's count via GCP API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, cpu-usage, vcpu

I would like to call `GCP API` call to get `vCPU's` total count. If all my instances use `280 vCPUs`, I want to get 280 in the response.
I can get the `vCPU` limit via the API metrics using `"/services/compute.googleapis.com/consumerQuotaMetrics/compute.googleapis.com%2Fcpus"`, but not the current `vCPU` count.
Is there a monitoring API for that purpose?

Help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I commented a similar question recently on the quotas. There is no API to get the current usage of a quotas, you can't achieve what you want programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As `@guillaume blaquiere` currently there is no way to count `vCPU` using GCP API. You can create `Feature Request` via [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) if you think it could be beneficial feature.

As a workaround, you can use `Cloud Monitoring` and use [Chart a single metric type](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer#find-me).

In `Metrics Explorer` you would need to choose:

- `Resource type:` VM Instance
- `Metric:` Reserved vCPUs
- `Aggregator:` sum

It would look like below:
[image]